# SQL Database SELECT question

Tags: sql, select, sybase, max

Need some help with an homework assignment on SQL

**Problem**

Find out who (first name and last name) has played the most games in the chess tournament with an ID = 41

**Background information**

I got a table called `Games`, which contains information...

- game ID
- tournament ID
- start_time
- end_time
- white_pieces_player_id
- black_pieces_player_id
- white_result
- black_result

...about all the separate chess games that have taken place in three different tournaments ....

(tournaments having ID's of 41,42 and 47)

...and the first and last names of the players are stored in a table called `People`....

- person ID (same ID which comes up in the table 'Games' as white_pieces_player_id and
  black_pieces_player_id)
- first_name
- last_name

...how to make a SELECT statement in SQL that would give me the answer?

Comment: It's not important actually - it's a Sybase Central thingy....oh nvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would aggregate a join to that table to a derived table like this:

```
SELECT a.last_name, a.first_name, CNT(b.gamecount) totalcount 
FROM players a
JOIN (select cnt(*) gamecount, a.playerid
      FROM games  
      WHERE a.tournamentid = 47
      AND (white_player_id = a.playerid OR black_player_id = a.playerid)
      GROUP BY playerid
      ) b 
ON b.playerid = a.playerid
GROUP BY last_name, first_name
ORDER BY totalcount
```

something like this so that you are getting both counts for their black/white play and then joining and aggregating on that.

Then, if you only want the top one, just select the `TOP 1`

Comment: hey, this is homework, you shouldn't just give him the answer!

Comment: I don't have SQL handy so I can't check... what error does it throw?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need to limit by tournamentID in your where clause, join with the people table on white_pieces_player_id and black_pieces_player_id, and use the max function on the count of white_result = win union black_result = win.

interesting problem.
what do you have so far?

hmm... responding to your comment

```
SELECT isik.eesnimi 
FROM partii JOIN isik ON partii.valge=isik.id 
WHERE turniir='41' 
group by isik.eesnimi 
having count(*)>4
```

consider using the `max()` function instead of the `having count(*)> number`

you can add the last name to the `select` clause if you also add it to the `group by` clause

sry, I only speak American.  What language is this code in?

Comment: +1, but he's not asking about the wins... Just `JOIN` two copies of the `GAMES` table, as you said on both columns, then `CNT(*)` and you can easily find who played most.

Comment: ah, you're right.  assumed they'd want the most wins.  the thing is, a playerID can be black or white, so he'll need a union

Comment: Not really. If you join the person table to the games tables on personID, it should create duplicate rows for each entry in the games table.

Comment: Yes, I like your solution, just not the first one I thought of.  I tend to use union when there's multiple equivalent sets.  Probably not what the instructor intended, tho.